# How to provide access to S3 buckets in a different AWS account using PrivateLink?

Tags: aws-private-link

I have been tasked to create a cross account access to S3 buckets. I created a cross account role and managed to access the objects in S3 buckets from another account. But I was asked to use PrivateLink for a secure connection. I know we can create a VPC endpoint and access objects in S3 bucket from private instances in the **same account**. How do we use PrivateLink to access the objects in S3 bucket from **another account**? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to use VPC Endpoint type Gateway for S3 in your account.
It will allow you to access any bucket in any account that you have permission.

A gateway endpoint is available only in the Region where you created it. Be sure to create your gateway endpoint in the same Region as your S3 buckets.

See more info on documentation below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

Comment: Thanks Azize for your response. I will try this. Is it the same case for Athena also? Let's say if I want to access Athena in Account B from Account A, should I follow the same steps?

Comment: VPC Endpoint type Gateway is only available for S3 and DynamoDB. Gateway can be used without any extra change. Other services, like Athena, use VPC Endpoint type Interface. Which also allow you to access Athena from any account which you have permission. But this one has some extra change.